# how to change url in mvc Framework

Tags: url

i use MVC and i want to change my url!I want to put my product's title in url.
look at this one

domain.com/buy/read/51

and i want something like this

```
domain.com/buy/read/some_text.
```

what is the best Optimal Solution???

```
domain.com/controllers/function/parameter
```

51 is parameter,i cannot remove it from url.can i?
after above problem,i decide to make a url like this

```
domain.com/buy/read/51/some_text
```

and attempt to change it with(by htaccess)

```
domain.com/buy/some_text
```

but i couldnot.
please help me.i spend 3 days with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depend of your framework (even it's your own). Usually, you can create a Route which match with your constraints.

Sorry if i can't help more, but i need more informations

Bye

Comment: you may can change it by htaccess but i don't know how and i don't think, it's the role of htaccess. domain.com/controllers/function/parameter is a good Route, why your 'some_text' can't be the paramater ?

Comment: because i want to select a product by a primary key means id,but title(some_text) isnot unique,is it clear???i just want to show title in url with this pattern,domain.com/buy/title.what is your suggestion???!!!a safe seggestion

Comment: Ok it's clear, but I don't get from where you want to get the ID (for your database query) if the ID of the wanted product isn't in URL (in this case : domain.com/buy/title). I think you must choose between have the ID in URL or set your titles unique :x.

Comment: ok,i think,i just have two choice,the first one it a url with this pattern domain.com/buy/a-unique-ID and the second way is domain.com/buy/a-unique-title.
now i have a url like this
domain.com/buy/ID/title-of-this-ID.
is it ok for search engine???

Comment: it seems correct, the ID allows you to get the product from database, and the title offers a  clearest URL (for both : visitor and referencing)

Answer (score 0):

i declared this codes in Bootstrap.what's your opinion??

```
if(isset($url[0]) && $url[0]=='buy'){
        require 'controllers/buy.php';
        $controller=new buy();
        $controller->Read($url[1]);
        return FALSE;
    }
```